# JavaScript. Error: is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Some problems with export/import in JavaScript. Where am I wrong?*

> import

```
`import Blog from '../pages/Blog`';
```

> export

```
class componentName extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Blog
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Blog;
```

> error

```
Line 13:16:  'Blog' is not defined  no-undef
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the ticks "``" from your import `import Blog from '../pages/Blog';`

Also, you haven't defined `Blog` anywhere in your export

#### Import

```
import Blog from '../pages/Blog'; // Can name the import anything when it's exported using the default keyword
```

#### export

I assume this file is named `pages/Blog`;

```
class ComponentName extends Component { // Capitalized class name
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Blog
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ComponentName; // use the same name as the class you want to export.
```